# Accessing iCloud NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification details from MonoTouch

Tags: ios5, xamarin.ios, icloud

Under MonoTouch, I'd like to access NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification (iOS5/iCloud key-value inbound update) notification data:

- NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreChangeReasonKey -> NSNumber
- NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreChangedKeysKey -> NSArray of NSString

There is a sample @ http://docs.xamarin.com/@api/deki/files/321/=iCloud.zip, but the code to access above is commented out and is buggy (how it tries to convert reason to integer is wrong). I am close here:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(new NSString("NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification"), 
delegate(NSNotification n)  
{
    NSDictionary userInfo = n.UserInfo;
    NSNumber reason = (NSNumber)userInfo.ObjectForKey(
        new NSString("NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreChangeReasonKey"));
    int ireason = reason.IntValue;
    NSArray changedKeys = (NSArray)userInfo.ObjectForKey(
        new NSString("NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreChangedKeysKey"));
});
```

I figured out how to get reason as integer. But how do I convert the NSArray of NSStrings to 
a simple string[]?? I've never had to work with the core Objective-C type wrappers before, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this helps ~ uses the IntPtr returned from the NSArray.ValueAt() method to new up an NSString and access the values you're after.

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver (
    NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.DidChangeExternallyNotification
    , delegate (NSNotification n)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cloud notification received");
    NSDictionary userInfo = n.UserInfo;

    NSNumber reason = (NSNumber)userInfo.ObjectForKey(NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.ChangeReasonKey);
    int ireason = reason.IntValue;
    Console.WriteLine("reason.IntValue: " + ireason);

    NSArray changedKeys = (NSArray)userInfo.ObjectForKey (NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.ChangedKeysKey);
    var changedKeysList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> ();
    for (uint i = 0; i < changedKeys.Count; i++)
    {
        var key = new NSString (changedKeys.ValueAt(i));
        Console.WriteLine("changedKey IntPtr: " + changedKeys.ValueAt(i));
        Console.WriteLine("changedKey (value): " + key);

        changedKeysList.Add (key);
    }
    // now do something with the list...
});
```

Comment: Thanks @CraigD. And should it help anyone else, here are the enum values you sent: public enum NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreChangeReason
{
    ServerChange = 0, 
    InitialSyncChange = 1, 
    QuotaViolationChange = 2
}